# Excel: array of results calculated from matrix evaluation

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I have a matrix

[image]

Solving it in Excel for certain values of a and b is not a big deal: I just MMULT the inversed first matrix and the second one.

But the problem is that I need to solve it for many combinations of a and b, like so:

[image]

The most straightforward solution would be to create a matrix for every combination separately, but that's extremely tedious. Can I do it in an easy way?

As a side question, I think it would be great if I could simply write my matrix into the formula input line itself, something like this:

=MMULT(MINVERSE( { {B15-4;-2;B15};{B16;-1;B16-2};{1;1;1} } ; {0;0;1} )

That would be a solution for my problem, but I have searched the internet and found no information on how to enter matrices or 2d-arrays into the input line. Is it possible and what's the syntax of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the 3x3 matrix, try instead inside MINVERSE():

```
 CHOOSE({1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9},B15-4,2,B15,B16,-1,B16-2,1,1,1)
```

(Or depending on regional settings, replace `,` and `;` with `;` and `\` respectively)

Comment: Amazing solution! For some reason it works in LibreOffice exactly as you wrote it, but doesn't in Excel 2003. Well, the fact that I can save it from Libre as xlsx but can't as xls(2003) mens Office 2003 doesn't have this functionality. I might be wrong though...

Comment: I suspect the issues in 2003 version may be related to local settings that define argument and array separators (as suggested above). The CHOOSE function has been available since the early days of Excel.

Comment: Yeah, it has the CHOOSE, and it puts the cursor between { and 1. I suspect that it cannot accept an array as first argument in 2003

Comment: Does it allow in the first argument: `{1;2;3\4;5;6\7;8;9}` ?

Comment: I just tried in 2003 version and seems ok, i think the separators should be the other way around though. Try instead: `=CHOOSE({1\2\3;4\5\6;7\8\9};B15-4;2;B15;B16;-1;B16-2;1;1;1)`. If that doesn't work for you i'm out of ideas.